# calloc doesn't set memory to zero

Tags: c

When allocating a 2D array, it looks like calloc does not set the memory to zero. I also tried manually setting the memory to zero and the same thing happened. Is there something else wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE_CONSTANT(t_value) ((size_t)t_value) 

#define SIZE_X SIZE_CONSTANT(15) 
#define SIZE_Y SIZE_CONSTANT(10)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool **buffer = malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof(bool));
    for (size_t x = 0; x < SIZE_X; x++) {
        buffer[x] = calloc(SIZE_Y, sizeof(bool));
    }

    
    for (size_t x = 0; x < SIZE_X; x++) {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < SIZE_Y; y++) {
            printf("x: %i, y: %i, %s\n", x, y, (buffer[x][y]) ? "true" : "false");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `bool **buffer = malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof(bool*));`

Comment: `malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof(bool))` will allocate an array of `bool` *values*, not an array of pointers. -it's very likely that `sizeof(bool) is smaller than `sizeof(bool*)`, which means you don't allocate enough memory.

Comment: Unrelated, but in the printf, `%i` is to print an `int`, not a `size_t`.  It may work on some systems but break horribly on others.  It should be `%zu`.

Comment: Technically you do not allocate a 2D array but a 1D array of pointer to `bool`. The 2d array can be allocated in a single line: `bool (*buffer)[SIZE_Y] = calloc(SIZE_X, sizeof *buffer);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a little if you don't plan on reallocating due to changes in the size of X or Y:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool *buffer = calloc(SIZE_X * SIZE_Y, sizeof(bool));

    for (size_t x = 0; x < SIZE_X; x++) {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < SIZE_Y; y++) {
            printf("x: %zu, y: %zu, %s\n", x, y,
                (buffer[x * SIZE_Y + y]) ? "true" : "false");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the changes I've made:

- Use one `calloc()` to get enough memory to contain all the elements. This involves less calls to `malloc()`/`calloc()`.
- The use of %i did not match size_t on most systems, so I updated to %zu.
- When referencing the fields, use `buffer[x * SIZE_Y + y]` to find the correct position.